# costmap does not subscribe /scan

Tags: gazebo, navigation, laserscan, costmap-2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, i have a litte problem, my costmap2d node does not subscribe my /scan topic which publishes sensor_msgs/LaserScan

Rosparam get /costmap_node/scan/:
{clearing: true, data_type: LaserScan, expected_update_rate: 0.5, marking: true, max_obstacle_height: 0.4,
min_obstacle_height: 0.08, observation_persistence: 0.0, topic: /scan}

In rxgraph i see that it does not subscribe my /scan topic, but my gmapping is unsing /scan and all works fine.

here is my costmap_common.yaml :
costmap/transform_tolerance: 1.0
costmap/footprint: [[-0.3, -0.3], [-0.3, 0.3], [0.3, 0.3], [0.3, -0.3]]
observation_sources: scan
scan: {data_type: LaserScan,
expected_update_rate: 0.5,
topic: /scan,
observation_persistence: 0.0,
marking: true,
clearing: true,
max_obstacle_height: 0.4,
min_obstacle_height: 0.08}

any ideas ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39343/costmap-does-not-subscribe-/scan/) by [pkohout](https://answers.ros.org/users/2803/pkohout/) on ROS Answers with karma: 336 on 2012-07-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try this configuration:

```
observation_sources: laser_scan_sensor

laser_scan_sensor: {sensor_frame: laser, data_type: LaserScan, topic: scan, marking: true, clearing: true, expected_update_rate: 0.5}
```

If you are still having issues, please post the rest of your configuration file. Not a lot of info was given to figure out your issues... Also, a screenshot of RXGRAPH would be nice alongside the output of this command:

```
rostopic info scan
```

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2012-07-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pkohout](https://answers.ros.org/users/2803/pkohout/) on 2012-07-22**:
have tried your configuration does't work. A picture of rxgrap : [http://i.imgur.com/DBeHE.png](https://i.imgur.com/DBeHE.png)

output of rostopic info scan:Type: sensor_msgs/LaserScan

Publishers:

- /gazebo (http://peter-XPS-15Z:35525/)

Subscribers:

- /hector_mapping (http://peter-XPS-15Z:50795/)

**Comment by [pkohout](https://answers.ros.org/users/2803/pkohout/) on 2012-07-22**:
global_frame: /map
robot_base_frame: base_link
costmap/update_frequency: 0.2
costmap/static_map: true
costmap/transform_tolerance: 1.0costmap/footprint: [[-0.3, -0.3], [-0.3, 0.3], [0.3, 0.3], [0.3, -0.3]]
observation_sources: laser_scan_sensor

**Comment by [pkohout](https://answers.ros.org/users/2803/pkohout/) on 2012-07-22**:
observation_sources: laser_scan_sensor

laser_scan_sensor: {sensor_frame: laser, data_type: LaserScan, topic: scan, marking: true, clearing: true, expected_update_rate: 0.5}

the whole config

**Comment by [pkohout](https://answers.ros.org/users/2803/pkohout/) on 2012-07-23**:
ok found my fault..i was setting observation_sources: laser_scan_sensor wrong.. now it works.
but now i get an error, [ERROR] [13, 5.46]: Client [/costmap_node] wants topic /scan to have datatype/md5sum [sensor_msgs/PointCloud/d8.. bur our version has sensor_msgs/LaserScan[...] drop connectino

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2012-07-23**:
Please post your configuration file again... I think you have a data type issue.

**Comment by [pkohout](https://answers.ros.org/users/2803/pkohout/) on 2012-07-23**:
ok was looking at my file once again and there was realy a little issue, i forgot to delete my laser_scan_sensor entry.
thanks a lot dude (:

**Comment by [pkohout](https://answers.ros.org/users/2803/pkohout/) on 2012-07-23**:
global_frame: /map

robot_base_frame: base_link

costmap:

update_frequency: 0.2

publish_frequency: 0.2

static_map: true

transform_tolerance: 1.0

footprint: [[-0.3, -0.3], [-0.3, 0.3], [0.3, 0.3], [0.3, -0.3]]

observation_sources: laser_scan_sensor

**Comment by [pkohout](https://answers.ros.org/users/2803/pkohout/) on 2012-07-23**:
laser_scan_sensor: {sensor_frame: laser, data_type: LaserScan,
topic: scan, marking: true, clearing: true, expected_update_rate: 0.5}

take a look at it...maybe there is somthing wrong i don't see